# Google Cloud Bucket with permission for just my user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I have Google Cloud project shared with few collages and few service accounts. I have `Owner` permission on the GCP project.

**I want to create a Google Cloud Storage Bucket that only me will have access to it**. So, the other users and service accounts in the projects will can't see it.

I created a new Google Cloud bucket (permission: `Uniform`) and went into the "Permission" sections. This list was already filled with inherits permissions. Since I want that only me will have access into this bucket:

1. I was added my self as Storage Admin
2. I removed the permissions for `Owner`, `Editor` and `Viewer` for this repository.

Now I have list with all the service accounts in the project. Unfortunately, Google not allowing me to remove the access of those service accounts:

[image]

How to revoke account to those service-accounts to this bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are inherited access which cannot be removed at bucket level.
Roles are always inherited, and there is no way to explicitly remove a permission for a lower-level resource that is granted at a higher level in the resource hierarchy.
As a `principle of least priviledge` grant minimum scope to the service accounts.

Comment: So, if I want to create a service account with full control permission to only specific bucket - it's impossible?

Comment: If the service account has full access (owner/editor) then it will have access to bucket reader also. That can not be revoked.